# MongoDB and Python :: Why is $group throwing a syntax error?

Tags: python, mongodb, syntax, group

I'm a complete beginner to MongoDB and have what I hope is a simple question about how to use the `$group` command in a MongoDB/python script:

Suppose I have a MongoDB instance, loaded with 1000s of JSON documents.  All documents match this format:

```
{
    "data1": "some data here",
    "moredata":
        {
            "data2": "more data here"
            ...etc...
        }
}
```

I'm trying to use `$group` to group and then count all the docs by `data1` and then `moredata.data2`.  Here's my python code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group:{
      _id: {data1: "$data1", data2: "$moredata.data2"},
      count: {'$sum': 1}
    }
  }
])
```

Running the above code produces a syntax error:

```
me@ubuntu/home/me$ /usr/bin/python3 test01.py
  File "test03.py", line 68
    $group:{
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
me@ubuntu/home/me$
```

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax` isn't very helpful feedback, and Google searches on `[python mongodb $group syntax error]` have been all over the map.  Then I remembered that sometimes it helps enclosing variables with `$` in quotes.  So, going for broke, I tried this variation (change on line 3 only):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    '$group':{
      _id: {data1: "$data1", data2: "$moredata.data2"},
      count: {'$sum': 1}
    }
  }
])
```

Now the script runs... but throws a Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test01.py", line 10
    _id: {data1: "$data1", data2: "$moredata.data2"},
NameError: name '_id' is not defined
```

According to [the MongoDB documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), the `_id` field is required for the `$group` command, so I'm betting that putting `$group` in quotes actually means I'm not calling that function/method.  My gut instinct is that the first version of code (`$group`, not `'$group'`) is correct.  But what am I doing wrong syntactically?  Thank you.

Comment: *"it helps enclosing variables with $ in quotes"* - well, yes, because at that point it is no longer a variable but a normal string. `$group` isn't a valid identifier. But `"$group"` obviously is a valid string. And neither should `_id` or `count` be without `"` or `'` around them because they aren't variables either, same then goes for `data1` and `data2`. You are writing python code here, not a raw MongoDB statement. See e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-mongodb-group-aggregation/

Comment: @luk2302  Ah.  Yeah, what you say makes a lot of sense.  I'm trying to learn this in one week; that's prob too much all at once.  Thanks!

Comment: See, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72630468/1409374) that has a complete `ipython` session that builds a `MongoDB` aggregation pipeline,  and using `pymongo`, queries a database, and stores the results in a `Pandas` `Dataframe`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thanks!  I did see this example earlier, and was able to use it to build a $match pipeline.  I'll revisit for $group

Comment: If you are used to Javascript, where the keys of objects can be left unquoted, then it might be confusing - in Python any unquoted values are basically always understood as variables (or keywords in the language like `if` `for` etc). A similar rule applies in JSON, where object keys must be quoted strings.